# Good slab font with Polytonic Greek support to go with Caecilia

Tags: font-recommendation

I am typesetting a book in a combination of [PMN Caecilia](http://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/pmn-caecilia) (body text) and [FF Clan](http://www.fonts.com/font/fontfont/ff-clan) (headings and other minor things).

In this book appears exactly *one* work in Greek: *μαῖα*. It appears in a footnote (which are set in Caecilia). Unfortunately, Caecilia—or at least the version of it that I have—does not support Greek, so I need to set the word in a different font. Having trawled through every single font I have on my machine, however, I have come to the conclusion that I have absolutely no slab fonts anything like Caecilia that support Polytonic Greek.

Uncle Google has led me to find [DejaVu Serif](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/DejaVu-Serif), which I suppose is at least relatively close, especially in a different alphabet. But it’s not *really* good.

I should be most grateful if anyone here knows of any good fonts that:

— look good
— are slab/similar to Caecilia
— have Polytonic Greek support
— is free (if possible—I doubt the company will let me buy a commercial font just for one word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyFonts offer [PF Centro Slab Pro](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/parachute/pf-centro-slab-pro/)

[image: PF Centro Slab Pro]

There are a number of fonts which have both μ and α, but that's the only one with ῖ as well. Even if you don't like the other characters, you might find that the Greek is a reasonable match for PMN Caecilia:

[image: PMN Caecilia]

Comment: That is a really good match, thank you! Shame it's not free (that was the fourth criterion, the one I forgot to include in the question)—sadly, I doubt they'll let me spend $80 just for one word.

Comment: What amazing luck—it turns out one of the other guys has Centro already, with a commercial license and all. Marvellous!

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this page? http://www.russellcottrell.com/greek/fonts.asp

It had a few interesting options. I looked at Hindsight Unicode by Darren Rigby, it's not bad in a pinch. But I'm sure there's better…

[image: Hindsight Unicode by Darren Rigby]

Comment: I did see that page (it's where I found DejaVu, I believe) and this font. I don't think it matches Caecilia too well, though, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a match (and I don't know of anything in the OSF/CC/Free category that's close -- DejaVu has a completely different architecture from Caecilia), the old design standby is to use a contrasting face that is *clearly intended* to convey "This here word is foreign. Get used to it."

On that basis, an Italic would work well. You would want to match x-heights, possibly by adjusting the point size, but most readers would identify it as a device to indicate a foreign word. This is a great deal more satisfactory than using something that will look like a mistake, which is what a not-quite-matching slab serif will give you.